# How do I build this robot car?

Tags: technic, shopping, power-functions, robotic

I want to start using more LEGO Technic, but I'm not sure what the best way is to buy the parts without breaking the bank.

I'd really like to make a robot like the ones shown in this video.

[Making Lego Car CLIMB Obstacles](http://Making%20Lego%20Car%20CLIMB%20Obstacles)
[image: screengrab]

They identify these parts:

SBrick https://www.sbrick.com/sbrick.html

BrickController 2 app ([Android](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbmZvY1FIa09id1ZOZ1gzTm1zVExqUnNxVFhUQXxBQ3Jtc0tsTGx0TnladF96ZEFQZlprTTB0UTR0YU9HU0lKVU02OF9DMDRybDA3VEFxV1o2Q29jVkdybzh3SkYzNlpidTI4OVgzMWtCSndZOVJDakdXQ0NOeUlwY2hoQU1CbE9TRjhtNHJFb0pLdGdLRmVaNURsTQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.scn.BrickController2))

PlayStation 4 wireless controller

But where do I get the rest?  Their channel recommends BrickLink, but that mostly seems to be individual pieces and vintage bits of Lego (unless I'm using it all wrong?)

Is there a low-cost way to buy most of the things shown here?  Should I buy a kilogram of used Technic elements on eBay and hope for the best?
Which motors, gearing systems, and batteries are they using here?  How are they connected to the SBrick? Is there a single kit that gets me 90% of the way there?

Comment: I think it would help if you could clarify a little what precisely you are looking for. For example: Are you looking for resources to show you how to use Technic parts? Are you looking for sources of third party kits like that particular model? Are you looking for more information about how to identity the parts in a model and how to source them on sites like BrickLink?

Speaking of BrickLink, some sellers do offer custom kits though it's a little buried in the interface. You are correct that the primary trade is in individual parts though.

Comment: good point - added some definition at the end

Comment: One more thought, I tracked down the actual video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwHHErfX9hI) and checked for more information and the About text for the channel explicitly says they don't publish building instructions, so it's unlikely you can contact the creator and get a parts list that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways you can start with LEGO Technic.

If you have no elements whatsoever the best (cost-efficient) approach is to buy a set that contains most of the parts. Or a couple of sets. Bulk lots could also be useful, however, they may not contain the most expensive elements (like motors). Specific elements could be acquired from Bricklink or BrickOwl.

It is also cost-efficient to buy sets that contain electronic elements already since these are usually more expensive when bought individually.

> Which motors, gearing systems, and batteries are they using here?

Motor - [Power Functions M-Motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8883-1) (as a "set") or [Electric, Motor 9V Power Functions M with Dark Bluish Gray Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58120c01) (as an "element")

Gears - multiple have been used in a video. You can find all of them in the [Technic, Gear](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=1&pg=1&catString=136&catType=P) section. These are used in the pictured model:

- [Technic, Gear 24 Tooth (2nd Version - 1 Axle Hole)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3648#T=C)
- [Technic, Gear Worm Screw, Long, Axle Opening Type II](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32905#T=C)
- [Technic, Gearbox 2 x 4 x 3 1/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6588#T=C)
- [Technic, Gear 40 Tooth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3649#T=C)

Battery - battery box used in the video is [Electric 9V Battery Box Power Functions (Rechargeable) with Dark Bluish Gray Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=84599#T=C). It is rather expensive and I suggest much cheaper and commonly found [Electric 9V Battery Box Power Functions (Non-Rechargeable) with Dark Bluish Gray Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87513c01#T=C) instead.

Please be advised both motors and battery boxes belong to the [Power Functions](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Power%20Functions#T=P) system which has been recently discontinued by LEGO.

> How are they connected to the SBrick?

SBrick is a controller and has connections compatible with the ones used by the Power Functions system. Each motor has a cable with a connector, so no extra cables are needed here.

> Is there a single kit that gets me 90% of the way there?

The Pictured model doesn't use a huge bunch of elements, so it is rather hard to define what 90% is. Personally, I would probably look for some used sets with [motors](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=58120c01&colorID=86&in=A) and [battery box](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=87513c01&colorID=86&in=A). And acquire the rest from Bricklink.

Comment: Great answer  - much appreciated!